# Node.js (CLI) にて実行環境の言語設定 (en-US, ja-JP 等) を取得する方法?

Tags: node.js

Windows を考慮しなければ `process.env.LANG` や `process.config.variables.icu_locales` が使えそうなのですが、Windows を含めると方法が見つかりません。

どなたかご存じないでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node `v0.12.0` 以上だと `Intl` が使えるようです。

```
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale) // → ja-JP
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js本体にはそのような機能が見つかりませんでしたが、言語設定を取得するnpmモジュールがありました。

https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-locale

Comment: 外部プロセスを起動するため遅いです...